# Should I choose voice expression AI project or face expression AI project if I'm beginner in Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, face-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm doing software engineering and I'm learning Artificial Intelligence course in the current semester, then I need to give the project at the end of this semester (after 3 months). So, my question is which project is recommended for me,  voice expression AI project or face expression AI project?

**VOICE EXPRESSION:** This software will listen user's conversation whole day then at the end of the day, it will show that how many bad words the user spoken, for how much time user got hyper, for how much time user got angry, etc.

**FACE EXPRESSION:** This software will monitor the screen of computer (for example teacher delivering lecture on ZOOM and camera of students are opened) then it will tell the user(or teacher) who is taking interest in user's lecture, who is confused, who wanna ask question etc.

So, If I'm a beginner in AI what project should I choose from those two projects? or should I choose easy project other than those two projects?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow avoid subjective questions to avoid downvote in future
https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, voice analysis seems to me easier than face analysis. To begin with, there is only one dimension, rather than two, and it would probably be easier to recognise words in a stream of sound than faces in a stream of images. However, I have a background in phonetics/signal processing, so sounds do look easier to me than images. If you've done image processing before, that might be better suited for you.

The key for a good project should not necessarily be how easy or hard it is, but whether it is something you are (a) interested in, (b) capable of achieving, and (c) relate to the course.

Also, be clear about what you want to achieve and how easy that is to determine: matching the sound pattern of a word is something much more objective than trying to identify if someone is bored or wants to ask a question based on facial expressions.